# How can I recursively parse an array where I count the number of keys possessing a specific value

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the problem: I extract the values from a DB and they are placed in an array. The array contains multiple sports teams. Each team has multiple members. However the number of members varies with each team.

So, I need to parse through the array and starting with team 1 count how many members it has, placing the value in a variable. Once complete it goes to team 2, then team 3 and so forth. When all teams are counted then the count results of each team will be presented on a web page.

It is irrelevant to the problem, but I am using Laravel. However, at this stage that is not my primary concern. Understanding a solution in raw php is a good start.

Comment: can you post an example of the input data ?

Comment: Have you tried writing the php for this? What does it look like so far? Where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: To keep things simple, the DB table has each row representing a player, or team member, so the array key / value will be organised the same. Simple example:

FirstName    LastName       Team

To be honest, I am struggling even to find where to start. I had the of creating a pivot table as this is possible in Laravel, but have not tried it yet.

Comment: Post your resulting array with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$teams = array(
    'Team 1' => array('Joe', 'Jane'),
    'Team 2' => array('Foo', 'Bar'),
);

$counts = array_map(function($team) {
    return count($team);
}, $teams);
```

See example here: http://ideone.com/zfvIw2

When dealing with Eloquent collections in Laravel, the answer will be a little different.

Answer (score 0):

So many options.

Best bet. Split the teams into different arrays. Then you can just look at the array lenght.

This would work using a multidimensional array as well...

Playerset [team] = array ( array ( name, age, sex, game), array( name, age, sex, game) ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic for this
for example :-
`$data=array('team1'=>array('a','b','c'),
              'team2'=>array('d','e'),
               'team3'=>array('f'));`

`$count=0;foreach($data as $key=>$val){
  $count[$key]=count($data[$key]);}`

`print_r($count)` will give you like this

`$count=array('team1'=>3,'team2=>2,'team'=>1);`

Hope this will help you in solving your problem